# (SQL) Using SELECT statements to display data with odd requirements

Tags: sql, oracle, select

So I'm taking a course on learning basic SQL (using Oracle), and I felt like I had become fairly fluent with using SELECT statements (grouping, joining, having, etc), but now I'm at a loss on how to deal with this latest problem.

I need to write a statement that would only display rows with more than one piece of data. So, say I had

```
COMPANY   PRODUCT
One       Car
One       Book
Two       Game
```

it should only list company 'One'. But I can't find anything online to help me.

Comment: Take a look at the HAVING clause (which is part of the group by clause).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select Company
From   YourTableName
Group By Company
Having Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

better way to know count of each company is :

```
Select Company,Count(*)
From   Table
Group By Company
Having Count(*) > 1
```